# java netbeans wrong working directory

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies

I am working on a project with some other projects and libs as dependencies. Recently I had to change one of the project dependencies, and move it to another location. Now when I run my program, its goes looking for files inside the working directory of that dependency. However, it still refers to the old location of the directory rather than the new one.

```
old directory : ../documents/github/project
new directory : ../documents/netbeansprojects/project
```

I have tried clean and building. I have also tried deleting the Netbeans cache, but it still keeps looking for the project in the old location, even though it shows a different path in the dependencies viewer.

Comment: Are you sure u do not have those dependencies in your configurations file ?If not how you deleted your cache ? After deleted the cache netbeans started as a new instance or project was still loaded there ?

Comment: @UtaAlexandru after deleting my cache i could still see the projects that were opened before i deleted it

Answer (score 0):

Copy your Netbeans shortcut .Right click on it,properties and put on your target value this value. "D:\Netbeans\NetBeans 8.0\bin\netbeans64.exe" --userdir E:\NetbeansHomes19 --cachedir "E:\NetbeansHomes19"  .

Take in consideration that  D:\Netbeans\NetBeans 8.0\bin\netbeans64.exe its your Netbeans installation Folder  and E:\NetbeansHomes19  its the place when u wanna keep your cache.Take care at spaces and quotes must be exactly like this example.For sure this will reset your cache and will start a new Netbeans instance.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to change the working directory in the project properties after moving my files. the solution:

project properties -> run -> working directory